# Dynamically selecting table in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm developing a multicultural site and in some cases I need to be able to read the data from different tables depending on selected culture. Here's an example:

```
IEnumerable<NewsEN> dataEN;
IEnumerable<NewsRU> dataRU;
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString() == "en")
  dataEN = db.NewsEN.ToList();
else
  data = db.NewsRU.ToList();

//Won't let me do this because implicit conversion isn't allowed here
var result = dataEN != null ? data : dataRU;

//Here's the important part where I want to stick the result in
var model = result.Select(....
```

(I know this looks noob as heck)

What I've tried so far is the Automapper. Not only it didn't work, it also seemed like an overkill for such a simple task, so we parted ways.
I've also thought about the Dynamic Linq lib - didn't try it yet though.
Third option would be executing the sql command with the table name as a variable which I can get from the If statement.

Also, there are like 20 methods which will have to rely on that code - should I look towards some smartass repository pattern?

Comment: Do `NewsEN` and `NewsRU` inherit from a base class? Might be advisable to do create one, then perform a type check. Otherwise you _might_ be able to give [Clay](https://clay.codeplex.com/) or similar library a whirl using dynamics as your vessel.

Comment: look at generic repository, then use IOC container to inject right repository by current culture

Comment: Hello and thanks,

These classes don't inherit from anything. I'm using code first, so I only created the NewsRU class to add a table, but apart from the name both classes are completely identical.

Comment: If you only need to read data, you can also use a stored-procedure to switch between the 2 tables based on the culture. In that way you do don't need to change your code.

Comment: I was thinking about this too. But then again - how do I choose between the stor-procs and the dynamic linq? I don't seem to be able to see the difference between these two approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement an interface on NewsEN and NewsRU and use `IEnumerable<INews>` or `IQueryable<INews>`. If you want to extract the queries as methods you can use generics where the constraint is INews.

Example:

```
interface INews
{
    DateTime PublishDate { get; }
}

class NewsRU : INews
{
     public string Text {get; set; }
     public DateTime PublishDate {get; set;}
}

...

public static void IQueryable<T> GetTodaysNews<T>(this IQueryable<T> source) where T:INews
{
    return from n in source
           where n.PublishDate > DateTime.Now.Date
           select n;
}

...

result.GetTodaysNews(); //whatever result is it will work
```

Also note that you should consider having one news table and having the language as a column in that table. While sometimes having different tables is better more often you will want the data in one table and the language as a column.

Comment: Thanks,

Them interfaces do not make much sense to me at that point tbh.
Is there any source you could suggest to start with the repository pattern? 
For now I'll just go with one table adding the culture column though.

Comment: Well you can just Google for the Repository pattern and different incarnations in .NET. TBH I am not a big fan of the repository pattern. I think the DataContext is the repository and LINQ is the interface... in most cases although I am the first to admit that there are exceptions. Adding a culture column is definitely a better solution for most cases with or without repository.

Answer (score 0):

> These classes don't inherit from anything. I'm using code first, so I
>   only created the NewsRU class to add a table, but apart from the name
>   both classes are completely identical.

---

Refactor your database scheme. Currently you're treating `NewsEN` and `NewsRU` as two different objects, although they contain the exact same properties. I therefore suggest that instead of having a table for both `NewsEN` and `NewsRU`, you simply have *one* table (`News`), with an extra field named "Culture".

You can then do like:

```
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString();
var data = db.News.Where(x => x.Culture == culture);
```

This will fetch `News` records based on the current culture. Also this makes it possible to extend with other cultures later. All you have to do, is set the culture to something else when adding a `News` record.

Comment: @ebb, Stilgar's approach is better because it doesn't require the db schema change. While in some cases the approach you demonstrated may be applicable, in high-volume environments, or in case the DB engine is running with something akin to MS SQL Server's SERIALIZABLE isolation level on for this db this will result with only some of the news working (e.g. you won't be able to retrieve 2 sets from the same table).

Comment: @zaitsman, `I'm developing a multicultural site` - I therefore assume that he have the possibility of changing the database scheme without too much hassle, as he's still in the development process.

Using the code above will _not_ result in retrieveing 2 sets from the same table. Please elaborate on isolation level `Serializable` for MSSQL. Translating the LINQ statement into SQL would be something like:

`Select * from News where Culture == "en"`. - And no, changing your infrastructure due to a poorly designed database scheme is a lot worse.